# in DAX or Power Query, How to return the max value for each row in?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to return the max value in this case dates for each row, I want to return the last time between worker 1, 2 and 3 for each row in column "Last time".

**Original Table and columns**

[image]

**Resulting table and columns**
[image]

In excel this is super simple MAX(A1,B1,C1), MAX(A2,B2,B2)....

in Dax I create a column

```
LT1 = MAX(example[Worker 1],example[Worker 2])
```

Then another column

```
Last Time = max(example[la1],example[Worker 3])
```

I get the right results but I was hopping for more elegant solution than that.

Thank You,

I try this as well but it did not work

```
MaxValue = MAXX('Table', {MAX('Table'[Column1]), MAX('Table'[Column2]), MAX('Table'[Column3])})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DAX** with a Calculated Column

```
MaxValue = MAXX({[Worker 1], [Worker 2], [Worker 3]}, [Value])
```

**PowerQuery** with a Custom Column

```
List.Max({[Worker 1], [Worker 2], [Worker 3]})
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery/M, more generically, you can do the max check on all columns at once without knowing their names

add column .. custom column... with

```
= List.Max(Record.FieldValues(_))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query M, you could also select a bunch of columns that have something in common without knowing their names.

For example, if you wanted to find the Max of all columns that were typed as `date` by the `#"Changed Type"` step, you could use this formula:

```
List.Max(Record.FieldValues(Record.SelectFields(_, Table.ColumnsOfType(#"Changed Type", {type nullable date}))))
```

***M Code to demo***

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords(
        {[Date1=#date(2023,5,1), Date2=#date(2023,3,7), Name="abc", Date3=#date(2022,12,31)]}),
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date1", type date}, {"Date2", type date}, {"Name", type text}, {"Date3", type date}}),      
    
    #"Add Max of Dates" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Most Recent", each 
        List.Max(
            Record.FieldValues(
                Record.SelectFields(_, Table.ColumnsOfType(#"Changed Type", {type nullable date})))), type date)
in 
    #"Add Max of Dates"
```

[image]